# Examples of reduced and integrally closed Noetherian domains

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying Serre's criterion, which basically relates the conditions $(R_1)$ and $(S_2)$ with reduced and integrally closed Noetherian domains. However, I would like to know some examples with more practical objects, to further enrich the research.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the "reduced" part of your request superseded by the "domain" part?

An abundant source of examples in algebraic number theory: Take any finite extension of fields $K/\mathbb Q$ and let $O_K$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $K$. These are all integrally closed Noetherian domains. They are actually normal domains, because the localization at any prime ideal is, in fact, a principal ideal domain.

An abundant source of examples in algebraic geometry: Coordinate rings of smooth, connected affine curves $C$ over a field $K$ are normal domains.